# I feel small bumps while driving

Tags: hyundai, alignment, wheel-balance

I just received a brand new Hyundai Santafe a week ago.
I started feeling a small bump (that also allow the rear (right) second row seats to vibrate). The small bumps start at very low speeds (20km/h)

I first thought the problem had to do with the tire pressure, so I had them checked but nothing changed.

Then I took it for both wheel balancing and alignment. The mechanic told me everything is perfect with the car (I was like... it's a brand new car). He also told me that the shock showas and the brake pads/disks were fine too. The problem is that I can still feel it...

I've tried everything in my knowledge but now i'm completely clueless.
Can you guys help me out?

- the bumps can only felt from the right side of the car (i'm assuming the rear right back side)
- total mileage of the car is 300.

Answer (score 2):

It could be you have a bad tire. If the belts are not put onto the tire correctly, the tire comes out malformed and can cause vibrations. The easiest way to tell this is by rotating your tire front to rear on the problem side to see if the vibration changes.

Ultimately, *this is a dealer issue*. All new vehicles come with what is called an "adjustment period" (at least in the States). This adjustment period is 12 months in most cases (at least at the dealerships I worked at it was this length). If you find an issue with your brand new vehicle during this time, you take it back and they make it right. The dealership themselves don't have to pay for this as it is covered under warranty.

Take it back to the dealership and tell them to fix it. Tell them what was already done (if they don't know already) and tell them you suspect there is a bad tire. Take the service manager for a ride and show them *exactly* what you are seeing/feeling so there is no doubt in their minds there is an issue.